# how could I reshape an image to let each 8x8 block become a vector with numpy/cv2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Suppose my image is 256x256x1. I need to reshape each 8x8x1 block in the image to a vector, which will result in a 32x32x64 tensor, in which each of the 1x1x64 vectors is the reshaped version of the corresponding 8x8 block. How could I do this with numpy or cv2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a series of reshapes and transpositions to get the result you want. For example, start by splitting the existing dimensions to add more:

```
a = a.reshape(32, 8, 32, 8)
```

The reshape does not need to copy data. Now move the dimensions you want to group to the back:

```
a = a.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
```

This creates a copy of the array with the blocks you want arranged contiguously. Now you can reshape just the blocks:

```
a = a.reshape(32, 32, 64)
```

This reshape won't copy any data either since you are preserving the memory layout.